# how to stop vb 6.0 application from picking icon from resource file

Tags: vb.net, vb6, resources, icons, exe

I have a VB project which has all the icons coming from a resource file (.res). Is there a way to control this, so that I can set the .exe icon from the icon assigned to my form? I cannot remove the resource file, as it has other dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

In the IDE, choose from the menu

Project -> your-application-name Properties

go to the Make tab, find the Application frame and set the application icon to be the same as the desired form.

Comment: This method doesn't work if your icons are stored in the resource file.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, your form icon is set from an icon in your resource file.  You have tried to go into your project and change the form's icon by changing the icon property.  Then, when you run your project, you don't see the change to the form icon.

If so, then your code is probably setting the icon from the resource file, which of course will override the property setting you make at design time.  Look for some line of code like this:

```
MyForm.Icon = LoadResPicture(x, vbResIcon)
```

where MyForm is the name of your form and x is the index of the resource in the file.  Comment this line out and see if it fixes the problem.

All that said, resource files are the better way to go.  You're going to have difficulty deploying your changes if you keep referencing files directly on your disk.  If you want to change the form's icon, you really ought to add it to your resource file (if it isn't already there; use the resource editor addin) and change the reference in the LoadResPicture statement.

Comment: Its the exe icon that is coming from the resource file. I am not able to stop it. Whenever I create an exe it just takes the first icon from the resource file. I cant find any code that seems to be causing this. Any idea as to how to stop this? I want the exe icon to be taken from the form.

Comment: Are you saying that the string "LoadResPicture" doesn't exist in your code?  Because that's the function that loads a picture from a res file.